# .htaccess code for dynamic redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've having a bit of trouble figuring out how to mass redirect a lot of files.

http://www.mysite.com/verify.php?site=mydomain.com

to

http://www.mysite.com/verify/mysite.com

And of course "mysite.com" will always be a different domain so that should be dynamic.

This is the code that I was using:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/verify\.php\?site=([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+)$ /verify/$1
```

Can someone please post what I need to change to make this work or a correct version of my code above?  Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**EDIT:**

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^verify/(.*)$ verify.php?site=$1 [L]
```

**Then try to load this in browser:**
http://www.mysite.com/verify/mysite.com

Comment: Tried that but doesn't look like there's any effect :/

Comment: That won't have any effect since http://www.mysite.com/verify/mysite.com is already working properly, just not the redirect.  I did try adding that though and it didn't do anything either.

Comment: The redirects are needing because I have a lot of people using those old pages and they need to be sent to the updated ones.

Comment: I've tried both of the codes your posted and neither made any difference, are they working for you?

Comment: This code that I wrote is not ment to do redirects only rewrites... I will look a bit more into it.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /verify\.php\?site=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /verify/%1 [L,R=301]
```

Or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^site=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^/?verify\.php$ /verify/%1 [L,R=301]
```